# TeXShop option "Wrap Lines: Never" does not work when using % !TEX root

Tags: texshop, magic-comment

I use the option "Line Wrap: Never" in TeXShop. It works fine, but when I open a file beginning with the magic comment `% !TEX root` the file is displayed with soft wraps (by word), even though the option "Line Wrap: Never" is ticked.

If I click again on the option "Line Wrap: Never", it displays correctly, but this is very annoying... Does anyone knows a bugfix?

Update: this bug disappear if you untick the option `Open master file` in the Misc 2 section.